# How to link a slider to specific blog post in php for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have blog slider on my main page of WordPress website and in that slider, each blog has its own page of continue reading.
When I click on 'Continue Reading' it should be linked to that specific blog post.

Comment: Sounds fine. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Just add an anchor to each slide. Put the permalink of the blog post in the `href` attribute.

```php
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($blogPostId); ?>">Continue Reading</a>
```